# Excel vba slow execution in big data worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is really slow my computer is taking some time to complete the action. I tried to use a fewer lines from `author_metadata` but even 40000 lines is too many.
Is there a faster alternative with excel VBA?

```
author_metadata = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("author_metadata").Range("A1:P542995").Value

allprofs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("allprofs").Range("A1:H4005").Value
Top200 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top200").Range("A1:B200").Value


m = 1

For j = 1 To 200
    For k = 1 To 4005
        If allprofs(k, 4) = Top200(j, 1) Then

        For i = 2 To UBound(author_metadata)

                If author_metadata(i, 10) = Top200(j, 1) Then

                    If allprofs(k, 2) = author_metadata(i, 12) Then
                    'do some data assigning between arrays like the next line
                    Top200Full(m, 1) = author_metadata(i, 1)

                   m = m + 1

                    End If

                End If

        Next i
        End If
    Next k
Next j

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top200full").Range("A2:Q75601").Value = Top200Full


End Sub
```

Comment: where does it hang? the last line?  Try defining the range at the end based on the array pasting maybe

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) will be able to help.

Comment: What you could do is add some progress indicator to this, to see where the bottleneck lies.  I'd start with placing it right at the start of the For k loop; something like `Debug.Print "j: " & j & " - k: " & k`.  Then see how fast or slow this updates.
Considering fixes: I can't see one so fast; it seems you have unavoidable complexity here. Apart from writing an XLL or C++-based COM add-in for this ;)

Comment: It is very slow inside the loops

Comment: The short answer is no. It is going to be slow. The code is not complex, the only operations are two assignments and one if. The problem here lies in the fact that with author_metadata containing 40000 rows, you still run that loop 200 * 4005 * 40000 = 32,040,000,000 times. It is going to take time

Comment: Ok, I understand that there is not a problem with the code but with the operation. Try to move the data to R or something like that and use that to do something similar would make any major difference or will it be the same? excel VBA is supposed to be slower than other languages. The actual data is 540000 rows! I used the 40000 just to see if i get any difference...

Comment: You could exit your loops when they do what they need to. That way you don't loop through each loop from beginning to end.

Comment: I need to find all possible matches so I can't tell if all are found until I check everything

Comment: Put the content of the Top200 and AllProfs into a dictionary. Then do one loop through author_Metadata and see if both entries exist, when it does add it to a Variant array then dump back to Excel. Additionally, you may be able to store fewer columns of data in the author_metadata Variant array, it doesn't seem like you need all the columns stored in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `AutoFilter()` method and `Dictionary` object

If I correctly grasped your logic, a possible code could be the following

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim Top200 As Variant, allproofFiltered As Variant
    Dim m As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim allproofFilteredDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Top200 = Application.Transpose(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top200").Range("A1:A200").Value)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("allprofs")
        With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Top200, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced range on its 3rd column (i.e. "State") with 1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header
                Set allproofFilteredDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
                For Each cell In .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1, -2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    allproofFilteredDict(cell.Value) = cell.Value
                Next
                allproofFiltered = allproofFilteredDict.keys
            Else
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("author_metadata")
        With .Range("J1:L" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Top200, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced range on its 3rd column (i.e. "State") with 1
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=allproofFiltered, Operator:=xlFilterValues '<--| filter referenced range on its 3rd column (i.e. "State") with 1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header                    
                .Resize(.Rows.count - 1, 1).Offset(1, -9).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Top200full").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

to use `Dictionary` object you must add its library reference to your project:

- click Tools->References
- scroll down listbox to "Microsoft Scripting Dictionary" entry and tick its check mark
- click OK

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes helps speed up my code;

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
Application.EnableEvents = False
```